# How do I add a receptacle outside off the porch light

Tags: electrical, receptacle, junction-box

I put in a gazebo in the back of the house and I want to install a receptacle from the only electrical source which is a porch light. I could just run some wire thru the base of the light and run it to the receptacle but it looks very cheesy. Is there a type of box or extender I could use to make up to code and look like it was done right

Comment: What kind of load will you put on it?  You would likely need a GFCI outlet.  How is the light attached to the wall and what is the shape of its base (a picture would help)?  Are you considering a surface mount box, or surface mount channel running to a surface mount box, or mounting it inside the wall?

Comment: Can you post photos of the existing configuration?

Comment: The light is presumably controlled by a wall switch which means that it *might* have only *switched* power at the light. If so, a receptacle fed from the light would only be powered when the light is switched on. However, it is possible that you have line power (not switched) available in the box. You would have to open it up and look at the wires. If there is only one cable in the box with one black, one white and a ground, then you don't have line power (always on) available in that box.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a box extension with knockouts, then run conduit down to a box with a WR weather resistant GFCI. If the cover or roof of the gazebo protects the location from rain a standard cover can be used but if it is wet your will need a hard use or in use cover (and the box itself will need to be listed for wet locations). Some folks don't like surface mount conduit if this is you you can box the conduit in. I have seen some very artistic "cover up's of conduit that made it look like a grape vine at first I did not realise it was conduit as they were on several posts.